# Serialize and Deserialize Binary Tree

Tags: java, serialization, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am working on the LeetCode problem [297. Serialize and Deserialize Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/serialize-and-deserialize-binary-tree/):

> Serialization is the process of converting a data structure or object into a sequence of bits so that it can be stored in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link to be reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment.
>
> Design an algorithm to serialize and deserialize a binary tree. There is no restriction on how your serialization/deserialization algorithm should work. You just need to ensure that a binary tree can be serialized to a string and this string can be deserialized to the original tree structure.
>
> [image]

I took inspiration from a correct solution I found to a similar problem on Geeks for Geeks: [Serialize and Deserialize a Binary Tree](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/serialize-and-deserialize-a-binary-tree/1) :

```
class Tree 
{
    public void serialize(Node root, ArrayList<Integer> al) 
    {
        //code here
        if(root == null) {
            al.add(-1);
            return;
        }
        al.add(root.data);
        serialize(root.left,al);
        serialize(root.right,al);
    }
    

    public Node deSerialize(ArrayList<Integer> al)
    {
        //code here
        if(al.get(0) == -1) {
            al.remove(0);
            return null;
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(al.get(0));
        al.remove(0);
        newNode.left = deSerialize(al);
        newNode.right = deSerialize(al);
        return newNode;
    }
}
```

I tried to adjust this approach for for the LeetCode problem. However, my attempt is not producing the desired output:

```
public class Codec {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public String serialize(TreeNode root) {
        if(root==null) {
            sb.append("^");
            return sb.toString();
        }
        sb.append(String.valueOf(root.val));
        serialize(root.left);
        serialize(root.right);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public TreeNode deserialize(String data) {
        if(data.charAt(0)=='^') {
            data = data.substring(1);
            return null;
        }
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(Character.getNumericValue(data.charAt(0)));
        data = data.substring(1);
        newNode.left = deserialize(data);
        newNode.right = deserialize(data);
        return newNode;
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: you are calling `serialize(...)`, but you are not doing anything with the return value. it should be `sb.append(serialize(...))`. In addition to that you need to move the creation of the `stringBuilder` into the `serialize` function.

Comment: The lower example works because you have no return value and you are writing right into the passed `arrayList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks:

- The Geeks-for-Geeks problem has a different interface: there the "serialisation" is interpreted as storing information in an array (vector), while with the LeetCode problem, serialization is about producing a string.
- Your code has a `sb` member that may be reused with a second call of `serialize`. Yet the correct functioning of `serialize` will at least require that `sb` initially represents an empty string.
- `String.valueOf(root.val)` gets appended, but there is no delimiter between two consecutive stringified values, so `deserialize` will not know how many digits belong to one value. In fact, your `deserialize` seems to assume each number only consists of one digit. This cannot be assumed.
- In `deserialize` the assignment `data = data.substring(1)` will only affect the local variable `data`, not the `data` variable of the *caller*. Note how the Geeks-for-Geeks solution has the advantage it gets an *array* to work with, which it can *mutate*. Strings are not mutable, so in the LeetCode problem we cannot use this strategy. You can get out of this by using a third function that you *will* pass a mutable array.

For instance:

```
public class Codec {
    // Encodes a tree to a single string.
    public String serialize(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return "^";
        }
        return String.valueOf(root.val) + ","
             + serialize(root.left) + ","
             + serialize(root.right);
    }

    // Decodes your encoded data to tree.
    public TreeNode deserialize(String data) {
        return deserializeArray(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data.split(","))));
    }
    
    private TreeNode deserializeArray(ArrayList<String> arr) {
        String value = arr.remove(0);
        if (value.charAt(0) == '^') {
            return null;
        }
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(Integer.parseInt(value));
        node.left = deserializeArray(arr);
        node.right = deserializeArray(arr);
        return node;
    }
}
```